# C# MSSQL alter table then modify values

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

While the following work fine in SQL Server Management Studio, it just won't work in C#:

```
DECLARE @PeriodID AS bigint;
SELECT TOP 1 @PeriodID = PeriodID FROM Periods ORDER BY PeriodID DESC;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME = N'PeriodID' AND TABLE_NAME = N'MobilePlans')
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MobilePlans ADD PeriodId bigint NULL
    END
    BEGIN
    UPDATE MobilePlans SET PeriodID = @PeriodID
    END
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MobilePlans ALTER COLUMN PeriodID bigint NOT NULL
    END
END
```

In C#, it keeps telling me `Invalid column name 'PeriodID'.` and after spending a couple of hours searching, I thought I'd ask here.

While searching, I came across http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/258520-problem-sqlcommand-t-sql-transaction, but I couldn't really translate my conditional query to that.

Why can't C# do the same as the Management studio?

Is there another way to do what the query does, that works in C#? I need to perform this on 400 databases, so I'd really like a script to do it for me.

Thanks in advance!

SQL server version is 2008.
Manager version is 2008 (10.0.2531).
.NET framework version is 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get "invalid column name 'PeriodID'" running it in Management Studio, *if the table doesn't already have the PeriodID column*.

Repro:

```
create table Periods (
    PeriodID bigint not null
)
go
insert into Periods(PeriodID) select 1
go
create table MobilePLans (
    BLah int not null
)
go
insert into MobilePLans(BLah) select 2
go
DECLARE @PeriodID AS bigint;
SELECT TOP 1 @PeriodID = PeriodID FROM Periods ORDER BY PeriodID DESC;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME = N'PeriodID' AND TABLE_NAME = N'MobilePlans')
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MobilePlans ADD PeriodId bigint NULL
    END
    BEGIN
    UPDATE MobilePlans SET PeriodID = @PeriodID
    END
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MobilePlans ALTER COLUMN PeriodID bigint NOT NULL
    END
END
```

The reason is simple - SQL Server tries to compile each batch completely. **If** the column already exists, then the UPDATE statement can be compiled. If not, you get the error.

If you put the update inside an Exec:

```
EXEC('UPDATE MobilePlans SET PeriodID = ' + @PeriodID)
```

Then it will be compiled at the point that the column does exist.

Comment: Oh my god.. That little thing solved my problem. How annoying that the compiler can't figure that one out. Guess I'm too used to get stuff handed on a platter by the C# compiler :) Thanks a bunch, Damien!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have a spelling mistake in your c# code.

The error is saying **PeriodeID** whereas your column name is **PeriodID**.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I translated it to make better sense. I just forgot to translate the error message, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Clarification:

1 - You would like to push this script it against many databases?

2 - Invalid column name 'PeriodeID', I cannot see a column called "PeriodeId", but "PeriodId", is this a typo?

3 - Can you try the same block without main BEGIN/END block?

Comment: 1: Yeah, about 400, but in the same instance.

Comment: 2: Forgot to translate the errormessage. It should be PeriodId as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Is the server collation **Case Insensitive** ? Because you're adding Period**Id** and then updating Period**ID**

Comment: No, it isn't. I forgot to mention when I tried to have consistant case with no positive effect.

Comment: I mean, it is. It is case insensitive. :)